# New site bootstrap first use, columns won't work the same

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I started learning Bootstrap and making a website after a PSD.Now.I have this heading and paragraph in my header that doesn't stack to the left side of the screen the same. I have used only one Bootstrap row. Now, I need to use a new row each time when I add new content on different lines? For example if I use: `col-md-12` for an item and then I use `col-md-4` for another item, while in the same row, it won't automatically create another row?

```css
header .row div #main_image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1; }
header .row div #logo {
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 1; }
header .row div h1 {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4vmax;
  width: 80%; }
header .row div p {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0.9vw; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="sass/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/Main.png" alt="Main Image" id="main_image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
                <h1> Picture perfect</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: header .row div #main_image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1; }
header .row div #logo {
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 1; }
header .row div h1 {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4vmax;
  width: 80%; }
header .row div p {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0.9vw; }

Answer (score 0):

Now, I need to use a new row each time when I add new content on different lines?

**Yes. Bootstrap use rows to orient itself to limit the content by lines.**

For example if I use `col-md-12` for an item and then I use `col-md-4` for another item, while in the same row, it won't automatically create another row?

**No. You have to count by yourself the limit of the 12 columns per line (row). After you reach the 12 columns limit your layout will break**

If you want to have more columns, you need to define your custom responsive grid, with the help of Bootstrap Less variables ([see here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)).

You'll mainly need to change these variables:

```
@grid-columns: Number of columns in the grid.

@grid-gutter-width Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
```